# assets:precompile error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres

when I run the following

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get the following error

```
rake aborted!
Settingslogic::MissingSetting: Missing setting 'production' in myapp/config/settings.yml
```

and what's in config/settings.yml file is below

```
defaults: &defaults
core:
name: Myapp
smtp:
  default_from:
  host: 
  port:
  domain:
  username:
  password:
  authentication:
  start_tls:

development:
<<: *defaults
web:
host: localhost:3000

test:
<<: *defaults
web:
host: localhost:3000
```

can someone help here please? What do I need to put in settings file if I deploy to heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just because you don't have a `production:` entry in your config file. You only have `development:` and `test:`.

For information, the [documentation](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic#5-suppressing-exceptions-conditionally) says `Raising exceptions for missing settings helps highlight configuration problems.` 
But you can suppressed this in production (see the link above)